# python OpenCV EarthMoverDistance out of memory error

Tags: python, opencv

Im trying to calculate distance between images using

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img1 = cv2.imread('F:/WIP/Programing/Nasa/111.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('F:/WIP/Programing/Nasa/111.jpg')

# image to signature for color image
def img_to_sig(img):
    sig = np.empty((img.size, 4), dtype=np.float32)
    idx = 0
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            for k in range(img.shape[2]):
                sig[idx] = np.array([img[i,j,k], i, j,k])
                idx += 1
    return sig


sig1 = img_to_sig(img1)
print(len(sig1))
print(sig1)
sig2 = img_to_sig(img2)
print(len(sig2))
print(sig2)
distance = cv2.EMD(sig1, sig2, cv2.DIST_L1)
print(distance)
```

> 120000 [[153.   0.   0.   0.]  [152.   0.   0.   1.]  [142.   0.   0.
> 2.]  ...  [ 23. 199. 199.   0.]  [ 28. 199. 199.   1.]  [ 19. 199. 199.   2.]]
>
> 120000 [[153.   0.   0.   0.]  [152.   0.   0.   1.]  [142.   0.   0.
> 2.]  ...  [ 23. 199. 199.   0.]  [ 28. 199. 199.
> 1.]  [ 19. 199. 199.   2.]]

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "f:/WIP/Programing/PythonMosaic/1.py", line 25, in 
distance = cv2.EMD(sig1, sig2, cv2.DIST_L1) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev)
D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:73:
error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 57600000000 bytes
in function 'cv::OutOfMemoryError'

Its trying to allocate 50+Gb ???

Comment: EMD is intended for histograms, not for an entire bag of pixels. what you did there is nonsensical. what you call "signature" isn't much of a signature/digest/hash at all, because that's the entire picture, with superfluous indices added. -- discard all that code. review the literature on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval, which is what you're apparently trying to do. the lesson here is to _not_ dive in head first into something you haven't informed yourself about. if you still do, expect things to make no sense.

Comment: I tried to follow this post https://theailearner.com/2019/08/13/earth-movers-distance-emd/

Comment: Thanx,  Im trying to compare two histograms using opencv. It works fine with cv2.compareHist function but I ant to try out cv2.EMD function fut when I try to input histograms I get "must be 32fC1 in function 'cvCalcEMD2'". Ive been stuck at it, tried to convert the array to float32 but no joy.

Comment: if there's a new error, please present the complete error and how it was caused.

Comment: particular point about EMD and the API: if the input signatures are of size1 and size2 each, the result is size1*size2 large... it follows that dumping an entire picture in there will be trouble. it'll handle any kind of data, but it better be orders of magnitude less data than the number of pixels (i.e. histograms, clusters, such stuff).

Comment: import cv2
import numpy as np

def getHisto(image3):
 try:
  hist = cv2.calcHist([image3], [0, 1, 2], None, [32, 32, 32],[0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
  hist = cv2.normalize(hist, hist).flatten()
 except Exception as e:
  print(e)
 return hist

img1 = cv2.imread('F:/WIP/Programing/Nasa/111.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('F:/WIP/Programing/Nasa/112.jpg')

img1_hist = getHisto(img1)
img2_hist = getHisto(img2)

hist_d = cv2.compareHist(img1_hist, img2_hist, cv2.HISTCMP_INTERSECT)
print(hist_d)

distance = cv2.EMD(img1_hist, img1_hist, cv2.DIST_L1,lowerBound=0)
print(distance)

Comment: note: pictures are about 200x200px